# How to make Matplotlib mouse interactive plots less laggy?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, mouseover, interactive

I want to make some interactive plots with Matplotlib, by plotting some extra graphics objects on mouse movements. Luckily, one of the interactive plot I want to present has already been coded and can be found on the Matplotlib website as a code example: [looking glass example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/event_handling/looking_glass.html).

Unfortunately, I find the performance very poor; in the gif you can see how much the rendering is lagging compared to the mouse movement.

[image]

Is it this the best performance that Matplotlib can provide for this task? I need to embed the interactive plots in some PyQt applications, so I could always switch to PyQtGraph, but if possible I would like to continue using Matplotlib.

Comment: One obvious and easy to fix performace hit is the use `draw()`. Use `draw_idle()` instead. Further improvement could be achieved with blitting. But that will be quite complicated in case the plot should also be zoomable/pannable.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, it improves the performance, but not enough. Using a scatterplot with more points is still too slow. While waiting for other comments/answers I will try to see the performance of PyQtGraph

Comment: Since implementing blitting is quite complicated, I wouldn't wait for such answers. But you could of course implement it yourself and ask about problems you encounter on your way.

Comment: Not a general solution, but for some widgets blitting can be enabled with a parameter. For example, 'useblit' drastically improved performance of RectangleSelector for me: 

```RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback, drawtype='box', useblit=True, button=[1], minspanx=5, minspany=5, spancoords='pixels', interactive=True)```

Answer (score 0):

The new package Quibbler might be helpful here:
https://github.com/Technion-Kishony-lab/quibbler

for transparency: I am one of the developers of Quibbler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).